# Investigating the presence of unit root in the following $X_t$

Tags: vector-autoregression, cointegration, unit-root, characteristic-function

I am given a model and need to calculate the unit-root of $X_t$ but it seems that there is no unit-root.

The model is given: $X_t = (x_{1t},x_{2t})'$

$$\Delta X_t = \alpha \beta ' X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $$

\begin{align}
    \alpha &= \begin{bmatrix}
           -0.50 \\
          0.25
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}
\begin{align}
    \beta &= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
          -1
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

I would therefore expect that $$\Pi = \alpha \beta ' = \begin{bmatrix}
           -0.5 & 0.5 \\
          0.25 & -0.25
         \end{bmatrix} $$

which means that I could calculate the unit root through the characteristic equation

$$\det(I-\Pi x)=0.$$

This gives me only one root $x=-\frac{4}{3}$. Therefore there is no unit-root for this process.

Is this correct?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question. When you posted on 
SE, you gave up ownership of the content under
[CC BY-SA 4.0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/licensing). 
If there are no answers, you may delete your own question 
(see 
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)
): just click the faint gray 'delete' at lower left (your 
account needs to be registered for this). Otherwise, the 
thread will remain according to SE's rules.

Answer (score 3):

What you are computing here is reduced rank of the long-run matrix, so confirming that there is cointegration. What we need is the roots of the characteristic equation in VAR(1) form, so not in this error correction form.

To get this, bring $X_{t-1}$ from $\Delta X_t$ to the r.h.s. to get
$$
X_t = (I+\alpha \beta ') X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t 
$$
So we are interested in the roots of the characteristic equation
$$
\det(I-(I+\alpha \beta ')z )=0
$$
or the solutions to setting the determinant of
$$\begin{bmatrix}
           1 & 0 \\
          0 & 1
         \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
           0.5 & 0.5 \\
          0.25 & 0.75
         \end{bmatrix}z=\begin{bmatrix}
           1 -0.5z& -0.5z \\
          -0.25z & 1-0.75z
         \end{bmatrix}
$$
to zero, which - see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281-0.5*z%29*%281-0.75*z%29-%28-0.5*z%29*%28-0.25*z%29%3D0) - does have a unit root.